# PHP - Buddy adding system with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a buddy system in PHP and MySQL, but I'm a little confused. I have a table called 'buddies' with three columns; user1, user2, pending. User1 will be one of the two buddies, user2 will be the other buddy. 'Pending' will either be 'true' of 'false'.

Then I need to display the users on the webpage. How do I select the only the column (either user1 or user2) that ISN'T their own user. My current code is

`$sql="SELECT * FROM buddies WHERE user1='$username' OR user2='$username' AND pending='1'";`

$query = mysql_query($sql);

Obviously, it will also show the user's own user as well as the buddy. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a union:

```
SELECT user1 from buddies WHERE user2 = '$username' UNION SELECT user2 FROM buddies WHERE user1 = '$username'
```

This would select user1 from all records where their own user is in user2, and vice versa and concatenate the lists.

(Note: You might want to double check the exact syntax, it's been a while since I've used the UNION keyword.)

Comment: syntax is right, just fix the `select user 2 from buddies` part, as it should be `user2`

Comment: @user1325291 No problem. If you're interested (and haven't already) have a quick read around set theory and the basic set operators. Understanding set theory often makes writing/understanding queries quite a bit easier :)

Comment: That didn't seem to work, but I figured it out using Aerik's answer. I used my old code and added this to the buddy thing: `if ($buddy['user1'] == $username) {
echo $buddy['user2'];
}
if ($buddy['user2'] == $username) {
echo $buddy['user1'];
}
 }` And it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

As you loop through your result in PHP (to display the buddies) only display whichever one is not equal to $username.

Answer (score 0):

How about using MySQL's 'if' function like this:

```
SELECT IF(user1 = '$username', user2, user1) AS buddy
FROM buddies
WHERE user1 = '$username' OR user2 = '$username'
```

Then, if you want to get other user data for those buddies (presumably, you have a users table with more details) you can get it like this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM (
    SELECT IF(user1 = '$username', user2, user1) AS buddy
    FROM buddies
    WHERE user1 = '$username' OR user2 = '$username'
) AS b
LEFT JOIN users AS u
    ON b.buddy = u.username
```